# What does this command mean? (IO redirection question)

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, rm

I am trying to figure out what this command is doing:

```
rm OUTPUT/* >> log_${ENV} 2>&1
```

Comment: Is the full stop part of the command?  Please put it in the question body and format it with markup so that it is clear what is and is not the command.

Comment: It looks *very* unnice, even in a build script (it seems to be some build script, or some data processing script). Honestly, this command looks so ugly that I am not sure if it is not part of some malicious code. What is that `${ENV}`, it means an environment variable named `ENV`!

Comment: Furthermore, this command is also false - what it tries to do: 1) removing all non-subdirectories in the directory `OUTPUT` (if `OUTPUT` has some sub-directories, the `rm` will fail with an error message) 2) logging all output, including the errors, into the file `LOG_` suffixed by the value of the environment variable `ENV`. Note also, the 2 reasons I can imagine to use an environment variable `ENV`: 1) some *very* beginner programmer seriously misunderstood something and wrote a VLQ script 2) it is a malicous code and its author tried to make it looking harmless for uncareful supervision.

Comment: The problem is that `rm` doesn't give any output for a successful deletion! There won't be anything in the logfiles! He should have written at least some like `rm -rvf OUTPUT/* >>log_${batchId} 2>&1`, and its author will probably write it on this way - after some years of unix experience.

Comment: Btw, I think your question is a good one, and the answer is enough objective to be not closed as "unclear" (probably all the unix pros will say roughly the same for that), but it seems I represent here a minority opinion. *Remain on the site*, your other questions might have a better luck in the future!

Comment: @peterh, If `rm` was aliased to `rm -vr` or something, the code might be more useful.  Perhaps prior code might provide better context.

Comment: @agc Yes, and it is also possible that `rm` is aliased to `cp` which will result they copying of all files into the alphabetically last directory entry, if it is a directory (else error message). It is possible, but it is not in the question :-) I think the questions should be interpreted always as default setting. Scripts typically ignore the aliases (maybe bash have same flag against it).

Answer (score 2):

the `rm OUTPUT/*` deletes all files in the `OUTPUT` Folder. `>>` appends the output of the command to a file called `log_${ENV}`. This does normally only redirect messages from stdout (rm without the `-v` parameter shouldn't write anything to stdout).

The `2>&1` redirects the stream 2 (this is stderr where rm writes its error messages) to stream 1 (stdout) which is redirected to the file.

So this command does remove the files and writes the errors into the logfile if there are any.

Comment: "deletes all files in the OUTPUT folder", except for dot-files, unless the dotglob option has been set...

Comment: @JeffSchaller ... in `bash`.

Comment: … which https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474518/ indicates the questioner not to be using.

Answer (score 2):

The command is identical to

```
rm OUTPUT/* 2>>log_${ENV}
```

As in [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474501), the curly braces won't do anything special here.  See also my answer there about `ENV`.

The command removes everything that `OUTPUT/*` matches.  If there are any errors, these are appended to the given output file.

Depending on the shell and what shell options are set, the `OUTPUT/*` pattern may in addition to all the names in the `OUTPUT` directory, also match the names of hidden files and directories, or it may not.

The `rm` utility will not produce any output on its standard output (which is why the command may be rewritten as above), but may give errors when deleting files that don't exist or that the current user does not have permission to delete, or if it tries to delete directories (without `-r`).  These error messages would be appended to the given file.  It's the use of `>>` (rather than `>`) that makes the shell open the output file for appending rather than for rewriting.

In the original command, `>>log_${ENV} 2>&1` would instruct the shell to open the file for appending and send the `rm` utility's standard output stream to it. The shell would then also, with the `2>&1` bit, send the standard error stream to the same place. The numbers `1` and `2` indicate the standard output stream and the standard error stream respectively, and when no number is used, the standard output stream is implied.

Answer (score 0):

`rm OUTPUT/*`

removes all files under the OUTPUT folder

`>> log_${ENV}`

appends the output to the file `log_${ENV}`

`2>&1`

redirects STDERR to STDOUT

References: [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Comment: By default rm doesn't write anything to ouput. You have to use `-v` parameter to show what was removed.

Comment: @mrc02_kr If the particular implementation of `rm ` has a `-v` option that does that.